# How to align input type file

Tags: html, input-type-file

I have the following code:

```
Select a picture: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
```

and I get this result:

[image]

I would like to have both the "Select a picture" text and the input in the same line (left-right) not top-bottom.

Also, I cannot figure out where the "No file selected" text is coming from. I would love to remove that text.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you share your CSS?

Comment: @Wowsk I don't really have css. All I did it was  `<center><font style="font-size: 3vh; color:grey">Select a picture: <input name="userfile" type="file" /></font></center>`

Answer (score 1):

You're limited in what you can do with CSS on a file-input button. I've made a jQuery plugin that lets you use a regular button as a file-input field that you can fully style as you wish.

Check it out on [Github](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload).

```
$("#mybtn").fileUpload();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z292qwob/1/).

I know you don't have jQuery or Javascript tagged, but like I said, CSS is limited in it's ability to style the File input types.

Comment: Thanks for this! Much nicer upload than just using the standard HTML form upload.

Answer (score 0):

For removing "No file selected" text use following css

```
input{
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Thanks,

Comment: This works but then my input is going to be 80px no matter the resolution or size of screen. I would love to find a solution where I don't have to define the size of the input to cut of the "No file selected" text. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

ok, for the issue of having the text and the input align vertically I found a rudimentary solution. Just using a table:

```
<table><tr><td><font style="font-size: 3vh; color:grey">Select a picture: </td>
           <td><input name="userfile" type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"/></font></td>     </tr>
</table>
```